# Why Drop down list box in a cell of grid data bound grid is not properly displaying

Tags: c#, syncfusion

I am developing a windows application using c#. I use syncfusion's controls instead of visual studios default controls. In my application I am using data bound grid. In this grid I have a cell which has another grid as drop down list. It works fine, but in one situation it is not properly displaying. Situation is:

- click in a cell which has grid as list and select its content
- instead of clearing content in it directly type a character
- list of 4 items get displayed which matched the typed character
- now clear content in a cell
- now list of all the records get displayed but I can see only one record at a time

It is like list id hiding behind something, I am not getting actually what is happening. Please reply me if you have solution to it. I will provide my code and screen shots if anybody need it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, close and open drop down list